# Listen tab not available in Windows Microphone Properties

Tags: windows-vista, audio, microphone

On my Vista laptop:

When I go to Control Panel > Sound > Recording, and double click on the Microphone in the recording device list, the "Microphone Properties" window opens. This window has 3 visible tabs: **General**, **Levels** and **Advanced**. The "**Listen**" tab is not available. How do I enable it?

**Sound Card**: Conexant High Definition SmartAudio HD2

[image]

Comment: Is the microphone jack otherwise working fine? Do you have the latest audio drivers installed? If so, perhaps your on-board sound card simply does not support the playback of microphone input through the speakers in real time.

Comment: The microphone jack works normally with applications. After your comment, I downloaded and installed the latest audio driver from the HP website, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the ability for 'stereo mix' to be supported as an input this is something that has to be enabled in the sound controller hardware.

Your drivers would need to expose this ability to Windows for it to present you with those options.

Thus either you need to update your drivers (the latest from HP is probably NOT the latest/most complete driver set for your card), or simply your card does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Download Virtual Audio Cable or install a virtual audio driver, it won't fully satisfy you're needs but I've done this and it helps with Windows XP and Vista, since computers are old or drivers don't fully patch. **It may not be free, but it will satisfy you and you only have to purchase once.**

https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/purchase.htm